# What does P mean after the from clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am try to make sense of this SQL code that compiles fine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT [eeeConfigurationId], [TimeInterval]
     FROM [dbo].[eeeConfiguration]) P
PIVOT
    (MAX([TimeInterval]) FOR [eeeConfigurationId] IN 
            ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
             [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
             [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
             [31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],
             [41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50]) )PV
```

What does that `P` after the from clause mean? And `PV` at the end?

I inherited code that says I should get a list in C# but SQL Server says int?

Never seen this before. I tried googling.

Comment: it's a table alias

Comment: It is a table alias and it is required for subqueries in the `from` clause for SQL Server and some other databases.

Comment: required even tho not used??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the names used for the derived tables.

`P` is `<alias for the source query>`
and
`PV` is `<alias for the pivot table>`.

The syntax for the `pivot` statement is as follows:

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,    
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,    
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,    
    ...    
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>    
FROM    
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)    
    AS <alias for the source query>    
PIVOT    
(    
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)    
FOR    
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]    
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],    
    ... [last pivoted column])    
) AS <alias for the pivot table>    
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

[Reference.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: why it says int not a list?

Comment: @Joe I don't understand what that statement means. What do you mean it says `int`?

Comment: on sql server when I click on the  plus sign in the list it says this returns integer.

Comment: @Joe Is this code part of a stored procedure or a function?

Comment: @Joe Then the stored procedure returns an integer (probably a status code or something similar). I don't know C# well enough to tell you how to get the result as a list though.

Answer (score 1):

P is the alias for the subquery, and PV looks like the alias for the pivot.

Run the query in a query window and see what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

It' a table alias - short name for using in queries. And you can select any name you want.
For example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT c.CustomerID, s.Name
FROM Sales.Customer AS c
JOIN Sales.Store AS s
ON c.CustomerID = s.BusinessEntityID ;
```

It's easier to operate with `c` and `s` than with `Sales.Customer` and `Sales.Store` names.
`AS` is optional. You can omit it.

More information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @Joe `AS` is optional, and there is no relation with name of alias and returned type

Comment: thanks! but how do I get it to return a list that I can do in c#.  I ranked expert in the pluralsight test for c# but SQL err no where near it.  I did mainly non db work in c#, and it shows :(

Comment: @Joe i think, it's another question